Is there a numerical integration method to choose the nodes wisely according to the analytically known integrand?
When solving a numerical integration such as
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \approx \sum_i w_i f(x_i)
$$
with analytically known $f(x)$ and definite $[a,b]$.
For most quadrature methods, the nodes $\{x_n\}$ are chosen according to a static rule regardless of the form of $f(x)$.
Absolutely, for a fixed number of nodes, the optimal choice of nodes depends on the expression of $f(x)$.
I wonder whether there is a numerical method to choose nodes "wisely", making the utmost of the information from $f(x)$?

P.S. One possible strategy is to choose the number of nodes increasingly and adaptively according to a specific error, but it is not elegant enough. I think a better strategy is to design a "selection rule" considering $f(x)$.


When you know the integral you can of course choose the nodes such that the $\approx$ becomes an equals sign. What did we achieve? We already know the integral.

All the Gaussian quadrature rules (Gauss-Legendre, Gauss-Laguerre, Gauss-Hermite, Gauss-Jacobi ....) take factors in $f(x)$ into account to align the weights and abscissae with the "dominant" regions of the integrand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature .

@KurtG. Of course the integral may be nonelementary.

@R.J.Mathar If I haven't made a mistake, the choice of nodes and weights in Gaussian quadrature method totally depends on the specific polynomials.

When we choose the weights for Gaussian quadrature we take $f$ to be a polynomial and the integral is a trivial thing but crucial to determine the weights. I have no idea what exactly you are having in mind with different types of $f$s.

@KurtG. Sorry for my unclear expression. For example, if $f(x)$ varies fast in a small subinterval, it's better to place the nodes more densely there to get a good approximation. In Gaussian-type quadrature method, for example in Gaussian-Legendre method, weights and nodes are totally determined by the Legendre polynomial, not taking into account the information of $f(x)$.
